# How to generate a preview URL in Twig

Tags: token, preview

I have a template intended for administrators (separate from the Craft control panel) where I'd like to generate tokenized preview links for unpublished posts (the same URL you get when you click on the "View" button from an entry page within the control panel). These links are intended for administrators to share with third parties so they can preview a page before it's published. Here's the Twig I have so far (which isn't working):

```
<a href="{{ element.url }}?token={{ craft.app.tokens.createToken() }}">Preview</a>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out:

```
{% set token = craft.app.tokens.createToken(["preview/preview", {"elementType": "craft\\elements\\Entry", "sourceId": 123, "siteId": 1}]) %}
<a href="{{ element.url }}?token={{ token }}">Preview</a>
```

Make sure `sourceId` and `siteId` are set correctly.